# What R function can I use to check if the values of a column are identical based on an attribute?

Tags: r, tidyverse

If your solution can contain a solution based on the tidyverse package that would be great.

Basically, I'm trying to group by a column titled "Attribute" and test whether all the values in the "Values" column are identifical.

This is my expected result:

[image]

As you can see - for Mustang, the Value column is all 1. So we are setting matches to = "Yes".

For Corvette and Charger, since one of the values is off, we are setting Matches to = "No"

I tried:

data <- group_by(Attribute) %>%
mutate(Matches = ifelse(first(value) != any(Value), "Yes", "No")

Didn't work. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The `any(Value)` iis not clear.  because `any(1)` returns TRUE whereas `any(0)` returns FALSE i.e. any value not equal to 0 returns TRUE

Answer (score 0):

The `any(Value)` is not really doing what we wanted as `any` returns TRUE/FALSE based on whether it have any Value greater than 0 or not.  In addition there are some typos (`data <- group_by(Attribute)` - it should be `data %>% group_by(Attribute)`)

```
> any(c(1, 0, 5))
[1] TRUE
> any(c(0, 0, 0))
[1] FALSE
```

We may need to check whether the number of distinct elements (`n_distinct`) is equal to 1 or not

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>%
    group_by(Attribute) %>%
    mutate(Matches = c("No", "Yes")[1 + (n_distinct(Value) == 1)])
    # // or using ifelse
    # mutate(Matches = ifelse(n_distinct(Value) == 1, "Yes", "No"))
```